# Writing a maths formula for flexGrow to adjust a div width with number of letter & window width as variables

Tags: javascript, html, css

If you run the snippet below you'll see I have a hover over effect on each div which opens up a buy it now button.. To make this work with different languages and different window widths I was hoping to make the width of each div dynamic depending on how many letters there are in the 'buy it now' div & the windows width.. So I've made a funky formula, but not sure of the maths of how to make it work across different window widths. Could someone help me with the maths?

The variables are:
flex grow, 
window width &
buyNowLetters (number of letters in the div)

```js
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', fms())

    function fms(){
        var shadeFinder = document.querySelector('.fms-wrapper')
        var shadeDiv = document.querySelectorAll('.fms-shade')
        var vw = window.innerWidth;

        //first load the right colors in to the divs
        shadeDiv.forEach(div => {
            div.style.backgroundColor = div.getAttribute("fms-bg")
        })

        //mouse hover events
        shadeDiv.forEach(div => {
            div.onmouseenter = function(event) {
                let target = event.target;
                target.classList.add('js-hover')
                var buyNowLetters = target.lastChild.innerHTML.length;
              
                //THIS IS THE FORMULA IVE BEEN TRYING WITH
                target.style.flexGrow = (20000/vw)*(buyNowLetters/19);
            };

            div.onmouseleave = function(event) {
                let target = event.target;
                target.style.background = target.getAttribute("fms-bg");
                target.classList.remove('js-hover')
                target.style.flexGrow = 1;
            };
        })
        
    }
```

```css
.fms-wrapper {
    height: 300px;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    margin: 100px 0;
    align-items: center;
}

.fms-shade {
    
    flex-basis: auto;
    flex-grow: 1;
    transition: all 0.8s;
    height: 100%;
    transform: scaleY(1);
    position: relative;
    margin-left:-1px;
    overflow: hidden;
    justify-content: center;
    display: flex;
    text-align: center;
    transition-timing-function: ease-in;
}

.fms-shade.js-hover {
 
    transition: all 0.2s;
    height: 120%;
    transition-timing-function: ease-out;
}


/* top bottom text before hover */
.fms-shade > .fms-shade__top {
    position: absolute;
    display: inline-block;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all 0.2s;
}
.fms-shade > .fms-shade__bottom {
    position: absolute;
    display: inline-block;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all 0.2s;
    bottom: 10px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}


/* hover over div */
.fms-shade.js-hover > .fms-shade__top {
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 1;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    transition: all 0.2s;
}
.fms-shade.js-hover > .fms-shade__bottom {
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 1;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    bottom: 10px;
    transition: all 0.2s;
}
```

```html
<div class="fms-wrapper">
        <div f1 class="fms-shade" fms-bg="rgb(189, 72, 72)"><p class="fms-shade__top">F9</p><p class="fms-shade__bottom">B </p></div>
        <div f2 class="fms-shade" fms-bg="rgb(65, 104, 148)"><p class="fms-shade__top">F9</p><p class="fms-shade__bottom">BW </p></div>
        <div f3 class="fms-shade" fms-bg="rgb(95, 189, 72)"><p class="fms-shade__top">F9</p><p class="fms-shade__bottom">BU W</p></div>
        <div f4 class="fms-shade" fms-bg="rgb(189, 168, 72)"><p class="fms-shade__top">F9</p><p class="fms-shade__bottom">BU NW</p></div>
        <div f5 class="fms-shade" fms-bg="rgb(189, 72, 183)"><p class="fms-shade__top">F9</p><p class="fms-shade__bottom">BU YOW</p></div>
        <div f6 class="fms-shade" fms-bg="rgb(189, 72, 72)"><p class="fms-shade__top">F9</p><p class="fms-shade__bottom">BUY NOW</p></div>
        <div f7 class="fms-shade" fms-bg="rgb(65, 104, 148)"><p class="fms-shade__top">F9</p><p class="fms-shade__bottom">BUY NOWW</p></div>
        <div f8 class="fms-shade" fms-bg="rgb(95, 189, 72)"><p class="fms-shade__top">F9</p><p class="fms-shade__bottom">BUUY NOWW</p></div>
        <div f9 class="fms-shade" fms-bg="rgb(189, 168, 72)"><p class="fms-shade__top">F9</p><p class="fms-shade__bottom">BUUY NOWWW</p></div>
        <div f11 class="fms-shade" fms-bg="rgb(189, 72, 183)"><p class="fms-shade__top">F9</p><p class="fms-shade__bottom">BUU YNOWWWW</p></div>

        <div f9 class="fms-shade" fms-bg="rgb(189, 72, 72)"><p class="fms-shade__top">F9</p><p class="fms-shade__bottom">BUUYNOWWWWW</p></div>
        <div f9 class="fms-shade" fms-bg="rgb(65, 104, 148)"><p class="fms-shade__top">F9</p><p class="fms-shade__bottom">BUUYNOWWWWW</p></div>
        <div f9 class="fms-shade" fms-bg="rgb(95, 189, 72)"><p class="fms-shade__top">F9</p><p class="fms-shade__bottom">BUUYNOWWWWWW</p></div>
        <div f9 class="fms-shade" fms-bg="rgb(189, 168, 72)"><p class="fms-shade__top">F9</p><p class="fms-shade__bottom">BUUYNOWWWWWW</p></div>
        <div f9 class="fms-shade" fms-bg="rgb(189, 72, 183)"><p class="fms-shade__top">F9</p><p class="fms-shade__bottom">BUUYNOWWWWWW</p></div>
        <div f9 class="fms-shade" fms-bg="rgb(189, 72, 72)"><p class="fms-shade__top">F9</p><p class="fms-shade__bottom">BUUYNOWWWWWWW</p></div>
        <div f9 class="fms-shade" fms-bg="rgb(65, 104, 148)"><p class="fms-shade__top">F9</p><p class="fms-shade__bottom">BUUYNOWWWWWWWW</p></div>
        <div f9 class="fms-shade" fms-bg="rgb(95, 189, 72)"><p class="fms-shade__top">F9</p><p class="fms-shade__bottom">BUUYNOWWWWWWWWW</p></div>
        <div f9 class="fms-shade" fms-bg="rgb(189, 168, 72)"><p  class="fms-shade__top">F9</p><p class="fms-shade__bottom">BUUYNOWWWWWWWWW</p></div>
        <div f9 class="fms-shade" fms-bg="rgb(189, 72, 183)"><p class="fms-shade__top">F9</p><p class="fms-shade__bottom">BUUYNOWWWWWWWWWWW</p></div>

        <div f9 class="fms-shade" fms-bg="rgb(189, 72, 72)"></div>
        <div f9 class="fms-shade" fms-bg="rgb(65, 104, 148)"></div>
        <div f9 class="fms-shade" fms-bg="rgb(95, 189, 72)"></div>
        <div f9 class="fms-shade" fms-bg="rgb(189, 168, 72)"></div>
        <div f9 class="fms-shade" fms-bg="rgb(189, 72, 183)"></div>
        <div f9 class="fms-shade" fms-bg="rgb(189, 72, 72)"></div>
        <div f9 class="fms-shade" fms-bg="rgb(65, 104, 148)"></div>
        <div f9 class="fms-shade" fms-bg="rgb(95, 189, 72)"></div>
        <div f9 class="fms-shade" fms-bg="rgb(189, 168, 72)"></div>
        <div f9 class="fms-shade" fms-bg="rgb(189, 72, 183)"></div>

        <div f9 class="fms-shade" fms-bg="rgb(189, 72, 72)"></div>
        <div f9 class="fms-shade" fms-bg="rgb(65, 104, 148)"></div>
        <div f9 class="fms-shade" fms-bg="rgb(95, 189, 72)"></div>
        <div f9 class="fms-shade" fms-bg="rgb(189, 168, 72)"></div>
        <div f9 class="fms-shade" fms-bg="rgb(189, 72, 183)"></div>
        <div f9 class="fms-shade" fms-bg="rgb(189, 72, 72)"></div>
        <div f9 class="fms-shade" fms-bg="rgb(65, 104, 148)"></div>
        <div f9 class="fms-shade" fms-bg="rgb(95, 189, 72)"></div>
        <div f9 class="fms-shade" fms-bg="rgb(189, 168, 72)"></div>
        <div f9 class="fms-shade" fms-bg="rgb(189, 72, 183)"></div>

        <div f9 class="fms-shade" fms-bg="rgb(189, 72, 72)"></div>
        <div f9 class="fms-shade" fms-bg="rgb(65, 104, 148)"></div>
        <div f9 class="fms-shade" fms-bg="rgb(95, 189, 72)"></div>
        <div f9 class="fms-shade" fms-bg="rgb(189, 168, 72)"></div>
        <div f9 class="fms-shade" fms-bg="rgb(189, 72, 183)"></div>
        <div f9 class="fms-shade" fms-bg="rgb(189, 72, 72)"></div>
        <div f9 class="fms-shade" fms-bg="rgb(65, 104, 148)"></div>
        <div f9 class="fms-shade" fms-bg="rgb(95, 189, 72)"></div>
        <div f9 class="fms-shade" fms-bg="rgb(189, 168, 72)"></div>
        <div f9 class="fms-shade" fms-bg="rgb(189, 72, 183)"></div>

        <div f9 class="fms-shade" fms-bg="rgb(189, 72, 72)"></div>
        <div f9 class="fms-shade" fms-bg="rgb(65, 104, 148)"></div>
        <div f9 class="fms-shade" fms-bg="rgb(95, 189, 72)"></div>
        <div f9 class="fms-shade" fms-bg="rgb(189, 168, 72)"></div>
        <div f9 class="fms-shade" fms-bg="rgb(189, 72, 183)"></div>
        <div f9 class="fms-shade" fms-bg="rgb(189, 72, 72)"></div>
        <div f9 class="fms-shade" fms-bg="rgb(65, 104, 148)"></div>
        <div f9 class="fms-shade" fms-bg="rgb(95, 189, 72)"></div>
        <div f9 class="fms-shade" fms-bg="rgb(189, 168, 72)"></div>
        <div f9 class="fms-shade" fms-bg="rgb(189, 72, 183)"></div>


    </div>
```

I'm not even sure if flexGrow is the best way to do this, maybe there is a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a javascript error to solve when the div is empty to solve it:

```
if(target.lastChild != null)
```

## Solution:

> you might need to small changes on the code, but this to give an idea of how to calculate the width

1. get the collapsed bar width using the following jquery

   > if you have another idea you can implement I'm short in time thats why i used the jquery:

```
const barWidth =$('.fms-shade').sort(function(a, b){
                                 return $(a).width() > $(b).width(); 
                              }).first().width();
```

2. get the current bar conent width using:

```
var contentWidth =target.lastChild.clientWidth;
```

3. calculate how many times you have to multiple the collapsed div width to show the content using the following code.

   > Math.ceil to get the nearest bigger integer

```
var flexMCount = Math.ceil(contentWidth/barWidth);
```

4. assign the number to flexgrow:

```
target.style.flexGrow =flexMCount;
```

Check the full code:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', fms())

const barWidth =$('.fms-shade').sort(function(a, b){
                                 return $(a).width() > $(b).width(); 
                              }).first().width();
                              
    function fms(){
        var shadeFinder = document.querySelector('.fms-wrapper')
        var shadeDiv = document.querySelectorAll('.fms-shade')
        var vw = window.innerWidth;

        //first load the right colors in to the divs
        shadeDiv.forEach(div => {
            div.style.backgroundColor = div.getAttribute("fms-bg")
        })

        //mouse hover events
        shadeDiv.forEach(div => {
            div.onmouseenter = function(event) {
                let target = event.target;
                target.classList.add('js-hover')
                if(target.lastChild != null)
                {
                //Get the collapsed bar width
                var contentWidth =target.lastChild.clientWidth;
                 var flexMCount = Math.ceil(contentWidth/barWidth); 
                
               
                  //THIS IS THE FORMULA IVE BEEN TRYING WITH
                  target.style.flexGrow =flexMCount;
                }
            };

            div.onmouseleave = function(event) {
                let target = event.target;
                target.style.background = target.getAttribute("fms-bg");
                target.classList.remove('js-hover')
                target.style.flexGrow = 1;
            };
        })
        
    }
```

```css
.fms-wrapper {
    height: 300px;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    margin: 100px 0;
    align-items: center;
}

.fms-shade {
    
    flex-basis: auto;
    flex-grow: 1;
    transition: all 0.8s;
    height: 100%;
    transform: scaleY(1);
    position: relative;
    margin-left:-1px;
    overflow: hidden;
    justify-content: center;
    display: flex;
    text-align: center;
    transition-timing-function: ease-in;
}

.fms-shade.js-hover {
 
    transition: all 0.2s;
    height: 120%;
    transition-timing-function: ease-out;
}


/* top bottom text before hover */
.fms-shade > .fms-shade__top {
    position: absolute;
    display: inline-block;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all 0.2s;
}
.fms-shade > .fms-shade__bottom {
    position: absolute;
    display: inline-block;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all 0.2s;
    bottom: 10px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}


/* hover over div */
.fms-shade.js-hover > .fms-shade__top {
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 1;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    transition: all 0.2s;
}
.fms-shade.js-hover > .fms-shade__bottom {
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 1;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    bottom: 10px;
    transition: all 0.2s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="fms-wrapper">
        <div f1 class="fms-shade" fms-bg="rgb(189, 72, 72)"><p class="fms-shade__top">F9</p><p class="fms-shade__bottom">B </p></div>
        <div f2 class="fms-shade" fms-bg="rgb(65, 104, 148)"><p class="fms-shade__top">F9</p><p class="fms-shade__bottom">BW </p></div>
        <div f3 class="fms-shade" fms-bg="rgb(95, 189, 72)"><p class="fms-shade__top">F9</p><p class="fms-shade__bottom">BU W</p></div>
        <div f4 class="fms-shade" fms-bg="rgb(189, 168, 72)"><p class="fms-shade__top">F9</p><p class="fms-shade__bottom">BU NW</p></div>
        <div f5 class="fms-shade" fms-bg="rgb(189, 72, 183)"><p class="fms-shade__top">F9</p><p class="fms-shade__bottom">BU YOW</p></div>
        <div f6 class="fms-shade" fms-bg="rgb(189, 72, 72)"><p class="fms-shade__top">F9</p><p class="fms-shade__bottom">BUY NOW</p></div>
        <div f7 class="fms-shade" fms-bg="rgb(65, 104, 148)"><p class="fms-shade__top">F9</p><p class="fms-shade__bottom">BUY NOWW</p></div>
        <div f8 class="fms-shade" fms-bg="rgb(95, 189, 72)"><p class="fms-shade__top">F9</p><p class="fms-shade__bottom">BUUY NOWW</p></div>
        <div f9 class="fms-shade" fms-bg="rgb(189, 168, 72)"><p class="fms-shade__top">F9</p><p class="fms-shade__bottom">BUUY NOWWW</p></div>
        <div f11 class="fms-shade" fms-bg="rgb(189, 72, 183)"><p class="fms-shade__top">F9</p><p class="fms-shade__bottom">BUU YNOWWWW</p></div>

        <div f9 class="fms-shade" fms-bg="rgb(189, 72, 72)"><p class="fms-shade__top">F9</p><p class="fms-shade__bottom">BUUYNOWWWWW</p></div>
        <div f9 class="fms-shade" fms-bg="rgb(65, 104, 148)"><p class="fms-shade__top">F9</p><p class="fms-shade__bottom">BUUYNOWWWWW</p></div>
        <div f9 class="fms-shade" fms-bg="rgb(95, 189, 72)"><p class="fms-shade__top">F9</p><p class="fms-shade__bottom">BUUYNOWWWWWW</p></div>
        <div f9 class="fms-shade" fms-bg="rgb(189, 168, 72)"><p class="fms-shade__top">F9</p><p class="fms-shade__bottom">BUUYNOWWWWWW</p></div>
        <div f9 class="fms-shade" fms-bg="rgb(189, 72, 183)"><p class="fms-shade__top">F9</p><p class="fms-shade__bottom">BUUYNOWWWWWW</p></div>
        <div f9 class="fms-shade" fms-bg="rgb(189, 72, 72)"><p class="fms-shade__top">F9</p><p class="fms-shade__bottom">BUUYNOWWWWWWW</p></div>
        <div f9 class="fms-shade" fms-bg="rgb(65, 104, 148)"><p class="fms-shade__top">F9</p><p class="fms-shade__bottom">BUUYNOWWWWWWWW</p></div>
        <div f9 class="fms-shade" fms-bg="rgb(95, 189, 72)"><p class="fms-shade__top">F9</p><p class="fms-shade__bottom">BUUYNOWWWWWWWWW</p></div>
        <div f9 class="fms-shade" fms-bg="rgb(189, 168, 72)"><p  class="fms-shade__top">F9</p><p class="fms-shade__bottom">BUUYNOWWWWWWWWW</p></div>
        <div f9 class="fms-shade" fms-bg="rgb(189, 72, 183)"><p class="fms-shade__top">F9</p><p class="fms-shade__bottom">BUUYNOWWWWWWWWWWWBUUYNOWWWWWWWWWWW</p></div>

        <div f9 class="fms-shade" fms-bg="rgb(189, 72, 72)"></div>
        <div f9 class="fms-shade" fms-bg="rgb(65, 104, 148)"></div>
        <div f9 class="fms-shade" fms-bg="rgb(95, 189, 72)"></div>
        <div f9 class="fms-shade" fms-bg="rgb(189, 168, 72)"></div>
        <div f9 class="fms-shade" fms-bg="rgb(189, 72, 183)"></div>
        <div f9 class="fms-shade" fms-bg="rgb(189, 72, 72)"></div>
        <div f9 class="fms-shade" fms-bg="rgb(65, 104, 148)"></div>
        <div f9 class="fms-shade" fms-bg="rgb(95, 189, 72)"></div>
        <div f9 class="fms-shade" fms-bg="rgb(189, 168, 72)"></div>
        <div f9 class="fms-shade" fms-bg="rgb(189, 72, 183)"></div>

        <div f9 class="fms-shade" fms-bg="rgb(189, 72, 72)"></div>
        <div f9 class="fms-shade" fms-bg="rgb(65, 104, 148)"></div>
        <div f9 class="fms-shade" fms-bg="rgb(95, 189, 72)"></div>
        <div f9 class="fms-shade" fms-bg="rgb(189, 168, 72)"></div>
        <div f9 class="fms-shade" fms-bg="rgb(189, 72, 183)"></div>
        <div f9 class="fms-shade" fms-bg="rgb(189, 72, 72)"></div>
        <div f9 class="fms-shade" fms-bg="rgb(65, 104, 148)"></div>
        <div f9 class="fms-shade" fms-bg="rgb(95, 189, 72)"></div>
        <div f9 class="fms-shade" fms-bg="rgb(189, 168, 72)"></div>
        <div f9 class="fms-shade" fms-bg="rgb(189, 72, 183)"></div>

        <div f9 class="fms-shade" fms-bg="rgb(189, 72, 72)"></div>
        <div f9 class="fms-shade" fms-bg="rgb(65, 104, 148)"></div>
        <div f9 class="fms-shade" fms-bg="rgb(95, 189, 72)"></div>
        <div f9 class="fms-shade" fms-bg="rgb(189, 168, 72)"></div>
        <div f9 class="fms-shade" fms-bg="rgb(189, 72, 183)"></div>
        <div f9 class="fms-shade" fms-bg="rgb(189, 72, 72)"></div>
        <div f9 class="fms-shade" fms-bg="rgb(65, 104, 148)"></div>
        <div f9 class="fms-shade" fms-bg="rgb(95, 189, 72)"></div>
        <div f9 class="fms-shade" fms-bg="rgb(189, 168, 72)"></div>
        <div f9 class="fms-shade" fms-bg="rgb(189, 72, 183)"></div>

        <div f9 class="fms-shade" fms-bg="rgb(189, 72, 72)"></div>
        <div f9 class="fms-shade" fms-bg="rgb(65, 104, 148)"></div>
        <div f9 class="fms-shade" fms-bg="rgb(95, 189, 72)"></div>
        <div f9 class="fms-shade" fms-bg="rgb(189, 168, 72)"></div>
        <div f9 class="fms-shade" fms-bg="rgb(189, 72, 183)"></div>
        <div f9 class="fms-shade" fms-bg="rgb(189, 72, 72)"></div>
        <div f9 class="fms-shade" fms-bg="rgb(65, 104, 148)"></div>
        <div f9 class="fms-shade" fms-bg="rgb(95, 189, 72)"></div>
        <div f9 class="fms-shade" fms-bg="rgb(189, 168, 72)"></div>
        <div f9 class="fms-shade" fms-bg="rgb(189, 72, 183)"></div>


    </div>
```

> [image: Upvote if you like it]

Comment: hey thanks for your reply, on my local sever when i hover over the divs, the barWidth is always 0, and the contentWidth is always undefined.. so it doesnt work. Don't understand how it works in the code snippet you sent

Comment: I added the jquery library as I mentioned before, maybe you missed it.

Comment: just copied the html part and it worked.. must have been some change in there. Thaaanks!!